# Telegram bot api. Имитация приема callback query от пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Ситуация такая: В теле бота прописано очень много реакций на callback-и от кнопок.

Как можно сымитировать получение от пользователя бота полученные данные callback через post запрос?

Дело в том, что мне нужно сделать рассылку по времени через schedule. Но проблема в том, что данные для рассылки хранятся именно в хендлере с реакциями на callback-и (их несколько сотен):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):


    if call.data == "hi":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'данные для рассылки')

#  таких if несколько сотен.
```

Можно ли сымитировать получение callback data от пользователя?

у меня есть вот такой кусок кода, с которым мне помогли ранее, но он почему то не срабатывает:

```
def job():
    class XClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
             self.message = message
             self.data = "hi" 
    callback_inline(XClass())
```

Comment: Зачем имитировать?

Comment: Просто создайте другую функцию и вызывайте её где вам угодно.

Comment: @Александр я не могу понять как мне получить данные callback_data без участия пользователя и нажатия им кнопки.

Comment: Рассылка как должна происходить? По времени или по какому то событию?

Comment: @Александр рассылка происходит по расписанию - через shedule. но в описанной сверху схеме одна проблема - она работает только посли приема от пользователя callback. а мне как раз нужно просто передать в функцию callback без участия пользователя.